# Why does this construction give a weak factorization system in the category of span diagrams?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

In Dwyer and Spalinski's classic paper *Homotopy Theories and Model Categories*, they describe homotopy pushouts by defining a model structure on the category of span diagrams in a given model category $C$. In their Prop 10.6, in proving this is a model category, specifically in proving the weak factorization axiom, they seem to implicitly use the fact that (in their notation) if a map $f$ is such that $f_a$, $f_b$, and $f_c$ are acyclic cofibrations, then $i_a(f)$ and $i_c(f)$ are again acyclic cofibrations. However, it is far from clear to me why that ought to be the case. It is easy to see that they are weak equivalences using 2-out-of-3, but I can't seem to find a reason they should be cofibrations.

Comment: Already answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360460/why-does-this-construction-give-a-weak-factorization-system-in-the-category-of-s